# decoding mp3 in windows phone 8 and directx

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx, mp3, decoder

I have to do a simple mp3 player with effect, 
to do this I need to wave stream for input to xaudio2, then I can add any effect I want

so I've tried SharpDx and seems that AudioDecoder class is not supported by windows phone
so there's a way to add effect to mp3?

To me is not really important to decode a mp3 but I search the way to add effect, (for adding effect I need a function/method with in input raw audio data) to an mp3

can be done?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible. MP3 decoding on mobile platform is usually performed directly by the hardware so you have no hook to modify the decoded stream (that's why all MediaFoundation APIs to allow this are not allowed on this platform). You could use a C++ native decoder (for example ogg) and do the streaming yourself, if this is the main purpose of your application (listening to music and applying effects), it could be feasible.

Comment: really thanks that's why I can't see any player with effect... by the way I live in europe I can make a mp3 decoder in c++ without pay anything :)